# Issue with the alamofire wrapper class with objectmapper in swift3

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire, objectmapper

I am trying to maintain a wrapper class for alamofire plus object mapper like this

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import AlamofireObjectMapper
import Alamofire
import ObjectMapper

class APIManager: NSObject {
static let sharedInstance = APIManager()
    public func performRequest<T: Mappable>(_requestURL: URL,method:HTTPMethod, headers: [String: String], parameter: [String: Any],success:@escaping (_ response: DataResponse<[T]>) -> Void, failure:@escaping (Error) -> Void)  {
    Alamofire.request(_requestURL, method: method, parameters: parameter, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers:headers)
        .responseObject { (response: DataResponse<T>) in
            print(response.result.value!)
            switch(response.result) {
case .success(_):
                    guard response.result.value != nil

                    else {
                        print("Error")
                        return
                    }
                DispatchQueue.main.async{
                    if response.result.isSuccess {
                        let responseValue = response.result.value
                        success(responseValue as! (DataResponse<[T]>)
)}

                    }
                break
            case .failure(_):
                if let error = response.result.error as? URLError {
                    print("URLError occurred: \(error)")
                      failure(error)
                } else {
                    print("Unknown error: \(String(describing: response.result.error))")
                     failure(response.result.error!)
                }
                break
            }
    }
    }

}
```

I am trying to call this wrapper from the class:

APIManager.sharedInstance.performRequest(_requestURL: loginAccessTokenURL!, method:.post, headers: Constants.Header, parameter:postParameters, success: DataResponse, failure: nil)

This is i am calling from viewdidload but i am getting the following error:
[Please see the image for error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2BOy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Success is a callback so replace it with the following:

```
APIManager.sharedInstance.performRequest(_requestURL: loginAccessTokenURL!, 
                                         method: .post, 
                                         headers: Constants.Header,
                                         parameters: postParameters,
                                         responseType: AnyObject 
                                         success: { (response) in 
                                         //Call returned back success. Handle Response.                                                                                                                  

                                         }, 
                                         failure: nil)
```

Edit:

```
class BaseModel: Mappable {

    required init?(map: Map) {
        mapping(map: map)
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {

    }
}

class APIManager: NSObject {
    static let sharedInstance = APIManager()
    public func performRequest<T: Mappable>(_requestURL: URL,
                                           method:HTTPMethod, 
                                           headers: [String: String],
                                           parameter: [String: Any],
                                           responseType: AnyObject,
                                           success:@escaping (_ response: AnyObject) -> Void, 
                                           failure:@escaping (Error) -> Void)  {

        Alamofire.request(_requestURL, 
                          method: method, 
                          parameters: parameter, 
                          encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
                          headers:headers).responseJSON { (response: DataResponse<T>) in
                          if response.result == .success {
                              success((responseType as? BaseModel)?.mapping(map: Map.init(mappingType: .fromJSON, JSON: response.result.value)))
                          }

        }
    }
}
```

I think this is what you're talking about. All your `JSON` models will now be `subClasses` of `BaseModel`. Your returned object in the success will be the initialised `responseType` object. In your case `responseType` would be `GetTravelShopsResponse`.

Comment: is there any way to pass "DataResponse" to the network wrapper class?

Comment: So you want 'APIManager' to handle the response?

Comment: oh are you trying to pass in a completion block to the success which is passed in from else where?

Comment: Yess i want to pass mappable class name to the wrapper also .

Comment: Pass that in as a property on the func. I've updated my answer to show that. Then you can use that to map ur response accordingly and return it in the success completion block.

Comment: But my code also need to be corrected right?? What will be the correct code for which i posted?

Comment: Updated my answer.